# Is the blueshift and redshift of electromagnetic waves in a gravity field correlated with quantum spacetime

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime

As far as I know when photons enter a gravity field the wavelength decreases and when leaving increases . Time dilation has been measured and space probes are accelerated near a gravity field with flybys adding 100s KM/S . The interactions of particles is limited to the speed of light and any length of spacetime is related to the gravitational mass . If a virtual particle pair is sensitive to quantum space time as defined by wavelengths of light , then could the virtual particle create momentum from annihilation along the redshifting electromagnetic axis contributing to a quantum gravity effect ? . The faster virtual particle would have slightly more velocity than the slower one and after annihilation momentum should be conserved with the higher velocity dictating direction of momentum .

Comment: There is no “electromagnetic axis”.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational redshift/blueshift does *not* require quantum spacetime. It happens in purely classical General Relativity.

You can also make an argument, based on simple energy conservation, that photons should redshift/blueshift even in Newtonian gravity.